# Visual Studio Code: Is there a way to automatically refactor JS imports when changing a directory (or file) name in the workspace?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I'm migrating to VSCode from WebStorm (for work reasons). In WebStorm, when you rename a folder/file in the list of folders/files, it will refactor your code so that that folder or file name change is reflected everywhere it is imported.

That is, if I change a folder 'components' to 'comps' from within the file explorer, all lines in all files which referenced 'components', e.g. 'import XYZ from ../components/XYZ' will be changed to 'import XYZ from ../comps/XYZ'. Is there a way to enable this in VSCode (either natively or perhaps an extension)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a setting and it works when renaming or moving files, but I'm not sure about directories.

On Windows you can access VSCode's Settings panel by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> simultaneously.

Then search the Settings for `Update imports` and you should see something that looks like this:

[image: import_setting_screenshot]

It should be set to prompt by default when you move/rename a file.

Comment: Yeah, I searched for you but I haven't found anything for directories, only files so far. I'll update my answer if I find anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
After some more tries, VS Code can actually rename paths after renaming folders. But it fails to do so sometimes. It will have some editor pop-out and it needs a little extra time to save the path change. Keep the editor open for a while to let the auto-refactoring finish.

I feel like it still does not support auto-refactoring of folder names until now.

But after enabling the settings of "Update Imports On File Move",
it can be done by opening a new folder and moving files to the new folder (all paths can correctly refactor), instead of directly renaming the folder.

P.S.
Sometimes the folder cannot auto-refactoring the correct path. Better close all opened files and consider moving files 1 by 1.